# jar file wont execute, no main manifest attribute

Tags: java, jar

I have the following java classes and text document in a file:

```
Board.class
BoardPanel.class
Frame$ActionHandler.class
Frame.class
manifest.txt
```

Where `manifest.txt` contains:

```
Main-Class: Frame
```

But when I type the following commands:

```
> jar cvfm gameOfLife.jar manifest.txt *.class
> java -jar gameOfLife.jar
```

It reports this error:

```
no main manifest attribute, in gameOfLife.jar
```

Have I got the wrong text in `manifest.txt`? Or is my error coming from something else?

Comment: The file should not be `manifest.txt` but `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`

Comment: Are these classes wrapped up in a package?

Comment: Yes @VishalK, should it be `gameOfLife.Frame`? or something...

Comment: Yes..If you have wrapped it in a package then it should be exactly in that way..`Main-Class: gameOfLife.Frame`..And look at my answer too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a new line in end in your `manifest.txt` file . Look at [Setting an Application's Entry Point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html). It says that:

> *Warning*: The text file must end with a new line or carriage return.
>   The last line will not be parsed properly if it does not end with a
>   new line or carriage return.

The content of your `manifest.txt` should be:

```
Main-Class: gameOfLife.Frame
```

(Don't forget to add new line in manifest file).Now keep this `manifest.txt` file just outside `gameOfLife` folder. Thereafter, on command prompt just move one directory up of `gameOfLife`. For example if your `gameOfLife` is in `c:\apps\gameOfLife` then on command prompt it should be:

```
C:\apps>jar -cvfm gameOfLife.jar manifest.txt gameOfLife/*.class
```

Comment: Yep, I've banged my head on the wall for hours over this stupid detail that Oracle won't fix. I think this is what the OP is experiencing...

Comment: You don't need it as a .mf file. Just a manifest.txt file will work fine.

Answer (score 4):

The *MANIFEST.MF* file must be inside the *META-INF* folder of your jar. Refer to this here: [Understanding the Default Manifest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/defman.html).

Note that having a *manifest.txt* file doesn't mean you have a default MANIFEST file. Also, it would be better if you create the MANIFEST file altogether when creating the jar instead of adding it manually after the creation (noted by BrianRoach's comment).

To update the MANIFEST file contents, follow the Oracle tutorial: [Modifying a Manifest File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/modman.html).

Comment: Re-reading his Q is *should* have actually added it when he created the `.jar` file. He specifies the `manifext.txt` as a *manifest-addition* in the `jar` command args

Comment: It still creates the same error (I've updated my code to `jar cvfm gameOfLife.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.mf *.class`. Am I still doing somethig wrong?